# How can I use a Namespace in two different files?

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I'm trying to use a Namespace in two different files.

First file:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
               var App= window.App || {};

               App.Form = can.Control.extend({... });
               window.App = App;
        });
```

Second file:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

               var App2 = window.App2 || {};

               App2.Form = can.Control({ 
               new App.Form();
               });

               window.App2 = App2;
        });
```

But I keep getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where you getting that error? I mean on which line?

Comment: What is the object `can`?

Comment: I get the error on this line: new App.Form();

Comment: im using canjs. Thats why there is a can there

Comment: That's two different namespaces :-) Have you made sure that your second file is executed after your first file?

Comment: How can I execute the second file after?

Comment: Javascript files are downloaded and executed in the order they appear in your HTML (unless you use the `async` or `defer` attributes on your script tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your second file

```
;(function(global) {

    var App = window.App || {}


    $(document).ready(function () {

           var App2 = window.App2 || {};

           App2.Form = can.Control({ 
           new App.Form();
           });

           window.App2 = App2;
    }); 

})(window);
```

Comment: I would do `})(window.App = window.App || {});`

Comment: The second file must be included after

Comment: How do I include it after?